Is there a way to condition-define the code for Delphi 11.2 specifically instead of 11.x?
I know I can use {$IFDEF VER350} to detect Delphi 11.x.
What can I use to detect 11.2 specifically? For instance, if 11.1 or 11.3 versions do not have an issue, but 11.2 does.

The duplicate question shows the additional constants defined for each update version. You will have to check whether there is constant for 11.2 and not for 11.3 to know you are dealing with 11.2 update.

@DalijaPrasnikar good catch, I forgot about those extra constants

VERxxx values are not updated during point releases.
There are CompilerVersion, RTLVersion, and RTLVersionXXX constants that you can use with the {$IF} directive.
CompilerVersion and RTLVersion are not guaranteed to always be updated on point releases.  Sometimes RTLVersion is, depending on the extent of updates made to the RTL in a point release, and if Embarcadero remembers to increment the value.
For your particular case, there are RTLVersion11x constants defined for each point release of 11.x:
RTLVersion: Comp = 35;
RTLVersion111: Boolean = True;
RTLVersion112: Boolean = True;
RTLVersion113: Boolean = True;

So, you can first check if RTLVersion (or CompilerVersion) is 35.x for an 11.x release, and then check if RTLVersion112 exists and RTLVersion113 does not exist, eg:
{$IF ((RTLVersion >= 35) AND (RTLVersion < 36))
      AND RTLVersion112
      AND (NOT RTLVersion113)}


Starting with 12.0, there is a new GetRTLVersion() function, which is documented as including a minor version for update releases:

Returns the RTL version number of the system unit when it is compiled. The RTLVersion constant can be used for the expression in the conditional compilation. GetRTLVersion includes two bytes:

Upper byte: It holds the RTL major version.
Lower byte: It holds the RTL minor version. Usually, the minor version is the number of the update release. For example, for RAD Studio 12 - Update 1, GetRTLVersion would return $2401.


But, this would be a runtime check, not a compile-time check, and it doesn't help you for 11.x and earlier versions.
